# Scrollable Grid with specified number of visible items

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Need to create scrollable grid with constant number of visible items(rows).

Grid needs to have 2 columns (always) and visible 3 rows (it can be 7 icons or 3 icons but there always should be space for 6 (if 3, there should be 3 empty spaces)).

It is important to fill whole visible space to 3 rows. Can't find property to get size of curent view or something. Tried to get some infos from `Windows.Curent.Bounds` or DisplayInformation class but can't get anything to specify my row height in app (that would be AppHeight/3 - too easy^^).

The thing is: the icons have different styles - 4 styles:

```
[0,0] - Style1
[0,1] - Style2
[1,0] - Style3
[1,1] - Style4
[2,0] - Again Style1!
```

If I could get height of AppBar i could just do

```
Row Height = (Windows.Current.Bounds.Height - AppBar.Height)/3.
```

But i can't find out how to do this. I know how to programmically add this icons to this grid with that styles but wonder if it is possible to get this result from Xaml file.

Ofc grid can have 8 icons (4 rows) but only 3 rows visible. I don't care if it would be gridview or grid in scrollviewer, but all items have to be clickable.

Comment: In case there are 4 rows, would the 4th row take up space of a single row or not?

Comment: General cleanup, especially whitespace.  It was a wall of text.

Comment: Sorry for text format. Always should be visible 3 rows so 4th should be under screen. But able to scroll ofc.